# Clean architecture practice for my Java project

Tags: java, oop, interface, architecture, clean-architecture

I would like to ask, if you have any idea, to make the architecture of my Java project cleaner.

```
  abstract class rdfDataChecker {
    List<T> data;
    // all abstract methods to check data... more than 20 methods. They all use the list "data". 
    }

    // the idea of this interface is, that all the data loaders can just use feedable.feed(List<T>). (we inject this dataChecker to the data Loader).
    interface Feedable {
    void feed(List<T>);
    }

   //implementations in different java frameworks.
    class specificRdfDataChecker extends rdfDataChecker implements Feedable{
    // implement all the methods.
    }


   class DataLoader {
   private Feedable feedable;
   public DataLoader(Feedable feedable) { 
   this.feedable = feedable;
   }
   }
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code review questions should be asked on CodeReview.SE, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is a common and acceptable pattern - it is even used in the Java libraries. See [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) that `extends` [AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) and `implements` [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: Thanks. The abstract class has about 20 methods and for finding a method, I have to search. Is it still fine? OR should I divide this class into different parts?

Comment: @javadeveloper - If **you** are having difficulties finding the right method in your own code then think how difficult it would be for someone else. Yes certainly refactor until using it is easy (for an arbitrary defiunition of *easy* of your choice).

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

1. Use [Strategy Pattern](http://bfy.tw/3oTn) instead of [Template Method](http://bfy.tw/3oTk) - it is always better to use composition over inheritance.
2. You should go through RdfDataChecker class and find out is it possible to extract some code to different class.
3. Make List data private - each class should encapsulate its own fields.